# Can't invoke class with override init method

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to create a simple game from a tutorial but the code does not seem to be working, so I assume Swift itself has changed since it was written. I'm using XCode 7.3.1 with Swift 2.2.

I'm creating a new class that inherits from SKScene and overrides the original init method:

```
import SpriteKit

class BallScene: SKScene {
    override init (size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)    
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The GameViewController class fails to create an instance of the BallScene class and reports errors (marked *>): Can't invoke initializer for 'BallScene' with argument list of type '(size: CGSize, () -> () )'

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

    class GameViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

      *>      let scene = BallScene(size: view.bounds.size) {
                // Configure the view.
                let skView = self.view as! SKView
                skView.showsFPS = true
                skView.showsNodeCount = true
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
      *>         scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
      *>         skView.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
//more code
}
```

Obviously the argument type of the init is being rejected, yet all seems to be ok.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.
Kw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure what you are doing. Why do you have a `{}` braces after init-ing the `BallScene`. I try your code, removing the `{}` works.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = BallScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
//more code
}
```

If this is not what you wanted, can you explain why you try to have a `{}` after init-ing `BallScene`?

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.